# How to disable security for Certain APIs in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am writing an application in Spring Boot. I am using the Spring boot default security mechanism. But I want to disable security for certain endpoints like `monitoring`, `healthcheck` etc.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you are trying to do, what application?

Comment: I am using spring boot application and using default spring boot security.

Answer (score 3):

You can add following configuration in Spring Boot application.properties

```
security.ignored= # Comma-separated list of paths to exclude from the default secured paths
```

Comment: A little more details might be helpful. Where do you put "security.ignored"? A reader might not be as familiar with the technology as you are...

Answer (score 1):

Use security.ignored=**Url Paths to be ignored** property in application.properties

Comment: Same answer is given by @Balachander.ra